# Accessing a method from other target to Today Extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, today-extension

I have an iOS app with two targets: the main (the app), and a today extension widget. In the main target I have a class called "TimetablesInformation", and if I call a method of that class from the own target everything goes right. But if I tried to access to that class from the other target (the widget) with this:

```
TimetablesInformation *info = [[TimetablesInformation alloc] init];
[info getTimes:@"1" forLine:lineName];
```

it crashes with this code error:

```
2015-12-26 01:48:04.420 Closer Times[15689:307103] __extensionContextClass != nil - 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libextension/libextension
82/libextension/Common/NSExtensionContext.m:164: Unable to find
NSExtensionContextClass (_NCWidgetExtensionContext) in extension bundle -
did you link the framework that declares the extension point?
```

TimetablesInformation is targeted to both targets on the right inspector of Xcode... So I have no clue about what can I be doing wrong... Could you help me, please?

EDIT: 
The getTimes method:
    -(NSArray *)getTimes:(NSString *)actualView forLine:(NSString *)lineName {

```
if ([actualView isEqual: @(1)]){
    if ([lineName  isEqual: @"Point A - Point B"]) {
        self.workingDayTimesArray = @[@"07:00",@"07:30",@"08:00",@"08:30",@"09:00",@"09:30",@"10:00", @"10:30",@"11:00",@"11:30",@"12:00",@"12:30",@"13:00",@"13:30", @"14:00",@"14:30",@"15:00",@"15:30",@"16:00",@"16:30",@"17:00", @"17:30",@"18:00",@"18:30",@"19:00",@"19:30",@"20:00",@"20:30", @"21:00",@"21:30",@"22:00",@"22:30"];
   }
}
```

I have tried with a void method, but I have the same error. If I call a method from the other target (main app) I haven't crashes, but if I do from my widget, yes I do. Have you an idea of the cause?

Comment: Post the getTimes method and whatever lineName is.

Comment: Have you enabled the target membership of the class for both app and widget?

Comment: The code was perfect, I just deleted the target, created a new one and now it works... Xcode mysteries...

Comment: You have to link NotificationCenter.framework

Comment: Me too. I removed the TodayExtension and added it again and it works again...

Answer (score 14):

It means that you or somebody accidentally removed a framework or library from the target you're running.

In my case, I was getting this crash error when somebody removed NotificationCenter.framework from "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" in General tab or "Link Binary With Libraries" in Build Phases tab. Thus, to fix it, you just need to add it again and everything will work.

So when you re-created TodayExtension target it linked NotificationCenter.framework by default. That's why everything worked for you after this.

Comment: Yep, you have to explicitly link to NotificationCenter in the Today extension.   I had removed NotificationCenter thinking an import statement in my extension code would automatically include it like in my app target, but it doesn't.

Comment: i had a similar crash with "_extensionContextClass" and adding the appropriate frameworks (in my case, UserNotifications.framework and UserNotificationsUI.framework for a Notification Content app extension) to the app extension stopped the crash!